# Jupyter notebook did not start properly on windows ubuntu bash

Tags: javascript, windows, bash, anaconda, jupyter

I would like to run jupyter notebook on Windows ubuntu bash.

First I have installed anadonda. anaconda should contain all the dependency to run jupyter notebook.

when I run jupyter notebook from ubuntu bash, following error occured.

What could cause this problem and how to resolve it?

[image]